# django rest framework serializing a model to return its str representation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say that my serializer looks like so

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity_instance = EntityInstanceSerializer(many=True)
    tags = EntityTagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ('id', 'entity_instance', 'tags', 'note', 'source')

class EntityTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EntityTagLabel
        fields = ('entity_tag_label',)
```

My tags model looks like this:

```
class EntityTag(models.Model):
    entity_tag_label = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entity_tag_label
```

Now this is fine and all, but my response looks like this:

```
   ...
        "tags": [
            {
                "entity_tag_label": "SENDER"
            }
        ],
```

Is it possible for my tags serializer to simply return the string representation of each tag? That way I would just have

```
        "tags": [
             "Sender",
        ],
```

as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) to do this. Something like:

```
class EntitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity_instance = EntityInstanceSerializer(many=True)
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='entity_tag_label',
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = ('id', 'entity_instance', 'tags', 'note', 'source')
```

Comment: Ah! Excellent, thank you. Out of curiosity, is it possible to have a slugfield make relational lookups? Similar to making queries like so Entity.objects.filter(entity_instance__label='somelable')

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But if you mean to filter Entities based on their label, then no, you can't do it with a SlugRelatedField. The purpose of serializers is not to filter your queryset. You can read about filtering in DRF [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters)